# yesod fill a specific form field in javascript

Tags: javascript, haskell, yesod

I have a simple yesod form:

```
aYesodForm :: Form Text
aYesodForm = renderDivs $ id
    <$> areq hiddenField "" Nothing
```

It generates roughly:

```
<input type="hidden" id="h2" name="f2" value="">
```

I want to fill it from javascript like:

```
document.getElementById('h2').value="foo"
```

But it would be bad practice to hardcode 'h2' into the .julius file, as it is auto-generated and could change.

the return type of runFormPost does not return the field ids it has generated, to interpolate into the .julius file.

What is the best way to fill yesod generated form field in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create your own ID when you generate your form using the FieldSettings parameter. FieldSettings data type can be found here: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/yesod-form/1.3.0/doc/html/Yesod-Form-Types.html

Something like this (untested):

```
<$> areq hiddenField (FieldSettings (SomeMessage "") Nothing (Just "myId") Nothing []) Nothing
```